# .js file does not execute through .php file, but does through .html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, include

I am a big newbie to PHP and JavaScript.  I found some code online using AJAX and JQuery to refresh a div every 10 seconds without refreshing the entire page.  I tried to quickly adapt it for the part of my messaging system that displays the messages in a conversation, so that the user would not have to refresh their page if they received a new message, however, it did not work.  I realised I must have made (several) errors, so now I am starting from the beginning, adapting the code I found step by step to the code I need.  I have come to a problem:

the code that loads the contents of the PHP file containing the contents (JQuery code (.js)) works with  on a file I called test.html, however, when I put the exact same code inside  and  tags on my view_conversation.page.inc.php page, the content of the div does not refresh.  Next, I used php to insert the test.html file, and, again, I got the same results - It worked perfectly if I went directly to test.html, however it didn't work at all (no errors were shown either) if I went onto my PHP page.  Both pages are in the same directory on the server.

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


<!-- Required header files-->
<script language="javascript" src="js/jquery_1.5.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="js/loaded_contents.js"></script>



</head>
<body>
<br clear="all">
<center>
<div style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:24px;">Auto Load Contents and Refresh Div Every 10 Seconds via Ajax, Jquery and PHP</div><br clear="all" /><br clear="all" />
<font style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size:12px; color:#00F">The content below will change every 10 seconds</font>
<br clear="all" /><br clear="all" />





<!-- Code Begins -->
<div class="vasplus_programming_blog_wrapper" align="center"><br clear="all" />

<div id="external_page_content_displayer">External page contents will be here</div><!-- External Page Content Displayer -->

</div>
<!-- Code Ends -->










</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me with this.  Thank you in advance.

Edit:This is the website with the original code
http://www.vasplus.info/50.html#.UwTDPJQgvps

I tried changing test.html to test.php; I got the same result

Comment: Can you show us your `AddHandler` directives in your Apache configuration file?

Comment: Where would I found my Apache configuration file?

Comment: jQuery 1.5.2 eh? Any reason for such an old version?

Comment: This code has been copied and is in the process of being edited.  Also, if I use an old one, it will be compatible with more (including older) devices!

Comment: @user3315726: By configuration file, I meant your VirtualHost. It's usually found at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`.

Comment: Oh, I am editing this in a password protected folder on a real server, so there is no VirtualHost involved

Comment: what is the url to the php page - you have coded the js links relatively to the document so if your page is www.domain.com/page.php it should work but if it is www.domain.com/something/page.php it won't.  try adding a slash before the js src: `src="/js/jquery.js"`

Comment: They are in the same directory;I did try that, however, and, as I would have assumed, it didn't work.  Thank you for that anyway though